# How to make multiple concurrent calls to async function collapse into 1 task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency, task

I have a C# `async` function like `SlowRewriteFolder()`, and I have multiple calls of this function coming in asynchronously.

If a call to this function is already processing, I want subsequent callers to not kick off the work that this function does again and instead wait on the same result (especially while the first one is still in progress).

How can I make it so that the `Task` created for the first call is shared among subsequent callers while it is still in progress?

I have considered caching the `Task` instance and returning that if it is available and clearing it when the work is complete, but is that the best approach?

Comment: Does `SlowRewriteFolder()` have any parameters? Is it a `static` method or an instance method? (BTW, it should be named `SlowRewriteFolderAsync`)

Comment: No parameters, instance method

Comment: Is there a return-value (i.e. `Task<TResult>`) or is it just `Task`?

Comment: It is Task<List<string>>

Comment: Returning a single mutable `List<>` to multiple callers is unsafe - you should change it to `Task< ImmutableList<String> >` or at least `Task< IReadOnlyList<String> >`

Comment: @RodrigoSalazar - Is there a point at which the results become stale? If I run the code now and then in 24 hours, should it use the results of the first call?

Comment: Related: [Block concurrent callers and return a single result from an async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401227/block-concurrent-callers-and-return-a-single-result-from-an-async-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have considered caching the `Task` instance and returning that if it is available and clearing it when the work is complete, but is that the best approach?

-ish. You'll need to ensure that "return or restart" logic is thread-safe.

Something like this...

- My simplistic approach uses a basic `lock()` inside a non-`async`-but-`Task`-returning method to do the job of swapping/resetting `Task` instances stored in a class field.

  - Note that the `volatile` keyword isn't needed here at all, [and reference-type assignment is atomic in the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192124/reference-assignment-is-atomic-so-why-is-interlocked-exchangeref-object-object).
  - Note [the usual `lock()` complications](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/lock-statement-best-practices):

    - The `lock()` target is a `private readonly Object` which is not locked by anything else - this prevents deadlocks or bugs caused by misbehaving consumers.
    - Shared state (i.e. the `this.cachedTask`) is always first *captured* in a local (the `task` variable) before being inspected or compared.
    - An outer optimistic `if( task is null || task.IsComplete )` guard means most invocations will never encounter the `lock()` at all.
    - Inside the `lock` another guard `if` prevents a consecutive thread from repeating the first thread's work.
- I'm sure my code can be improved though: I'm sure there's probably a lock-free way to do this (and by "lock-free" I don't mean that the `lock` is still there but buried in library code, [like in `ConcurrentDictionary`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs#L561)) but [I mean completely lock-free](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14011849/159145).
- BTW, the `Interlocked.Increment( ref _invokeCount )` in `SlowRewriteFolderImplAsync` is just for demonstration purposes: it's to prove that `SlowRewriteFolderImplAsync` is only ever entered twice (in this example). It's unrelated to the logic in `SlowRewriteFolderAsync`.
- **Also**, don't use `Task< List<T> >` in situations like these... or more generally: don't use a mutable `TResult` with `Task<TResult>` when a single `Task<TResult>` may (or will) be `await`ed by multiple callers - this is because the current <sub>(albeit loose)</sub> convention in .NET is that <sub>(sans documentation to the contrary)</sub> the end-receiver of a `Task<TResult>` becomes the *owner* of the `TResult` contained within - this isn't a problem when `TResult` is immutable (or at least, is a read-only interface), as there's no risk of multiple end-receivers mutating `TResult` and breaking each other - but when `TResult` is a mutable type (e.g. some POCO with `get; set;` auto-properties) - *or worse*: a non-thread-safe mutable type, like `List<T>`) then that's when programs fall apart.

  - This is why my code below returns `IReadOnlyList<String>` instead of `List<String>`. If you want to be extra-robust in your own code then you should consider returning `ImmutableArray<T>` or `ImmutableList<T>`  as those provide stronger-yet guarantees about immutablility that `IReadOnlyList<T>` does not.

```cs
public class FolderRewriter
{
    private readonly Object lockObj = new Object();
    private Task< IReadOnlyList<String> >? cachedTask;

    public Task< IReadOnlyList<String> > SlowRewriteFolderAsync()
    {
        Task< IReadOnlyList<String> >? task = this.cachedTask;

        if( task is null || task.IsCompleted )
        {
           lock( this.lockObj )
           {
                if( this.cachedTask is null || this.cachedTask.IsCompleted )
                {
                    this.cachedTask = this.SlowRewriteFolderImplAsync();
                    task = this.cachedTask;
                }
                else
                {
                    task = this.cachedTask;
                }
            }
        }

        return task;
    }
    
    private static Int32 _invokeCount = 0;

    private async Task< IReadOnlyList<String> > SlowRewriteFolderImplAsync()
    {
        Int32 c = Interlocked.Increment( ref _invokeCount );
        
        await Task.Yield();
        
        const String FMT = nameof(SlowRewriteFolderImplAsync) + "(), UtcNow: {0:o} Invoke Count: {1:N0}";
        FMT.FmtInv( DateTime.UtcNow, c ).Dump();
        
        return Array.Empty<String>();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

async Task Main()
{
    FolderRewriter rewriter = new FolderRewriter();
    
    // First:
    {
        Task< IReadOnlyList<String> > task0 = rewriter.SlowRewriteFolderAsync();
        Task< IReadOnlyList<String> > task1 = rewriter.SlowRewriteFolderAsync();
        Task< IReadOnlyList<String> > task2 = rewriter.SlowRewriteFolderAsync();

        Debug.Assert( Object.ReferenceEquals( task0, task1 ) );
        Debug.Assert( Object.ReferenceEquals( task1, task2 ) );

        IReadOnlyList<String> result0 = await task0.ConfigureAwait(false);
        IReadOnlyList<String> result1 = await task1.ConfigureAwait(false);
        IReadOnlyList<String> result2 = await task2.ConfigureAwait(false);
        
        Debug.Assert( Object.ReferenceEquals( result0, result1 ) );
        Debug.Assert( Object.ReferenceEquals( result0, result2 ) );
    }
    
    // Second:
    {
        Task< IReadOnlyList<String> > task0 = rewriter.SlowRewriteFolderAsync();
        Task< IReadOnlyList<String> > task1 = rewriter.SlowRewriteFolderAsync();
        Task< IReadOnlyList<String> > task2 = rewriter.SlowRewriteFolderAsync();

        Debug.Assert( Object.ReferenceEquals( task0, task1 ) );
        Debug.Assert( Object.ReferenceEquals( task1, task2 ) );

        IReadOnlyList<String> result0 = await task0.ConfigureAwait(false);
        IReadOnlyList<String> result1 = await task1.ConfigureAwait(false);
        IReadOnlyList<String> result2 = await task2.ConfigureAwait(false);
        
        Debug.Assert( Object.ReferenceEquals( result0, result1 ) );
        Debug.Assert( Object.ReferenceEquals( result0, result2 ) );
    }
}
```

Gives me this output in Linqpad - as you can see, the `SlowRewriteFolderImplAsync` method is only invoked twice, not 6 times:

[image]

Note that it gets far more gnarly if you want to use `CancellationToken` with `SlowRewriteFolderAsync` as the `SlowRewriteFolderImplAsync` will only have access to the `CancellationToken` of the first invocation, so subsequent invocations cannot be canceled.

Comment: I think that this answer is essentially an attempt to reinvent the [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) type!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias No. `Lazy<T>` can only be initialized _once_ - whereas my code shows how the `Task` can be restarted anew an unlimited number of times after each completion.

Comment: You are right, fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a component similar in shape with the [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asynclazy-1) type (also available in the [Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) library by Stephen Cleary), that has a behavior tailored to your needs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an asynchronous operation that is invoked lazily on demand, can be
/// invoked multiple times, and is subject to a non-concurrent execution policy.
/// Concurrent observers receive the result of the same operation.
/// </summary>
public class AsyncCollapseConcurrent
{
    private readonly Func<Task> _taskFactory;
    private volatile Task _task;

    public AsyncCollapseConcurrent(Func<Task> taskFactory)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(taskFactory);
        _taskFactory = taskFactory;
    }

    public Task Task
    {
        get
        {
            Task capturedTask = _task;
            if (capturedTask is not null) return capturedTask;
            Task<Task> newTaskTask = new(_taskFactory);
            Task newTask = newTaskTask.Unwrap().ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                _task = null;
                return t;
            }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach |
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
                TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
            capturedTask = Interlocked
                .CompareExchange(ref _task, newTask, null) ?? newTask;
            if (ReferenceEquals(capturedTask, newTask))
                newTaskTask.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler.Default);
            return capturedTask;
        }
    }

    public TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter() => Task.GetAwaiter();

    public ConfiguredTaskAwaitable ConfigureAwait(bool continueOnCapturedContext)
        => Task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
}
```

Usage example:

```
private readonly AsyncCollapseConcurrent _asyncLazy;

//...

_asyncLazy = new(() => SlowRewriteFolderAsync());

//...

await _asyncLazy;
```

The `AsyncCollapseConcurrent` ensures that the `taskFactory` will not be invoked concurrently, by creating a cold nested `Task<Task>` using the `Task<T>` constructor, and starting this task only in case the atomic [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange) operation succeeds. Otherwise, in case the race to update the `_task` field is won by another thread, the current thread discards the cold `Task<Task>` without starting it.

I have used this technique for implementing various `AsyncLazy<T>` variants, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340177/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-once/65714904#65714904) (with retry) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467426/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-lazily-on-demand-and-called-again-when-the/68478716#68478716) (with expiration).

In case your `SlowRewriteFolderAsync` method returns a generic `Task<TResult>`, you can find a compatible generic `AsyncCollapseConcurrent<TResult>` class [here](https://gist.github.com/theodorzoulias/39d63727dd17e704ddd79c64e7916897).

Answer (score 1):

If you only ever want the task to run once with multiple callers then the easy way is with `Lazy<T>`.

Try this:

```
public Lazy<Task<List<String>>> SlowRewriteFolderAsyncLazy =>
    new Lazy<Task<List<String>>>(() => SlowRewriteFolderAsync());
```

You then call it like this:

```
Lazy<Task<List<String>>> lazy = SlowRewriteFolderAsyncLazy;
Task<List<String>> task = lazy.Value;
List<String> value = await task;
```

The task within the `Lazy<>` type doesn't begin to run until the first caller invokes the `.Value` property, so this is safe to define `SlowRewriteFolderAsyncLazy` as a property.

All subsequent callers get the same completed task.

Comment: The OP has not specified the desirable behavior in case the operation fails, but I guess that caching the error and never retrying the operation is not the desirable behavior.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Probably true. One step at a time IMHO.

Comment: Also the OP has not said explicitly that they want to invoke the asynchronous operation only once. My guess is that they just want to avoid concurrent invocations. As soon as an operation is completed, they'll be happy to start a new one. That's how [Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73438603/11178549) has interpreted the question, and I would bet my money on that interpretation. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Me too. I did ask the OP about that but they ignored my question so I went with the question at face value.